# Is that possible to use SIP in LAN network?

Tags: sip, lan

I don't know enough about SIP. As far as I know SIP can not be used in LAN. But it's features are very good. I want to use it for a LAN messenger (with video conference facilities).

Is there any way of using SIP in LAN network ?

Comment: The answer is yes. SIP was primarily designed with LANs in mind and is in fact one of its major shortcomings since the core standard (RFC3261) doesn't deal with internet elements such as NAT.

Comment: Trying to make sense of the question I guess we don't understand what feyelati means by "LAN"?

Answer (score 2):

The SIP protocol can be used over any reliable transport (TCP, XMPP, instant messaging channel, etc...) to a service (e.g. a server such as a SIP proxy) that knows how to route the SIP INVITE message from the caller to the callee.  e.g. If you send an INVITE to bob@foobar.com, there's needs to be a service that knows how to find "bob" and deliver the message.  Likewise, when Bob sends back his response messages back, the messages need to route back to the caller who sent the original INVITE.

And you can do SIP without a server - provided the computer already have a connection (direct or indirect) to the other computer intended for the call.

But SIP isn't anything special.  If you were to invent your own video conferencing protocol, it would probably look a lot like SIP.  SIP's primary job is for both sides of a call to exchange IP/port candidates for connecting directly in addition to codec and bandwidth negotiation data.

After the SIP messages are exchanged, ICE/STUN/TURN take over and RTP packets typically flow.  SIP isn't used in the call except to end the call.

What are you really trying to do anyway?

Comment: I have a academic project to 'Create a LAN messenger using SIP'.I'm not sure what should I do

Comment: you should just use a SIP client to do that. Ignore the LAN part - SIP runs over IP, so you've got that one covered

Comment: SIP uses unreliable UDP by default so it doesn't need a reliable transport. In addition SIP and XMPP are equivalent protocols and you can't layer one on top of the other.

Comment: As a developer who has shipped several video call products based on SIP, I can tell you definitively that SIP works over ANY protocol (TCP, UDP, and other channels).  So I'm a bit miffed at the downvote. The person was asking a very broad question about SIP and I gave a broad answer.

Comment: I also updated my answer to reflect that SIP is supported over UDP.  Depending on the nature of the product UDP vs TCP is up to the implementor.

Comment: The down vote is because SIP cannot use XMPP, or other similar IM protocols, as a transport. XMPP could be considered an equivalent protocol to SIP not a transport layer for it. Your answer classifies XMPP in the same category as TCP when in fact they are completely different.

Comment: SIP is not married to UDP or TCP and can be "tunnelled" or multiplexed on top of connections used for other services. And while you will find recommendations in the RFC that give specifics about UDP/TCP, you'll also find the RFC permits other transports. Tunneling is very useful as it allows you bridge SIP across different types of clients and backend services without having to establish a seperate UDP session (or TCP connection) for SIP.

Comment: Put it another way - when you scale a voice/video service to the size of a telco (possibly with interop to other networks), the bridging of SIP across existing service connectiosn becomes a very powerful device. Hence, a casual suggestion to imply that SIP can be used over XMPP - the messages would just need to be encapsulated with XML. I know all this, because I have shipped a very well known applicaiton that tunnells SIP. In bends the RFC slightly, but interops perfectly other clients that only speak TCP-SIP.  Follow up with me offline if you want more details.

Comment: @selbie: Tunnelling SIP over XMPP seems like a very convoluted approach to me. XMPP/Jingle are very similar protocols from a feature point of view so a much better solution would be a SIP-to-XMPP/Jingle gateway and do protocol translation. I still think you should remove the inference that SIP can be transported over XMPP and IM channels from your answer as it could easily confuse readers (and it will get rid of my downvote :)).

Comment: I think we just share a difference of opinion clouded by the fact that it's difficult to describe anything significant in these attention deficit boxes.  The original question is ambiguous at best, so it's hard to gauge the appropriateness of my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thread is Old but still I would like to contribute to this. There are various SIP server like http://www.officesip.com/index.html which works in LAN and can be connected to hardware phone too and soft client also. 
Jitsi is open source cross platform SIP/xmpp client:https://jitsi.org/
And if you want to XMPP server Openfire is the best:http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

I hope this will definitely help someone..!